# Making a JavaScript app to merge multiple files

Tags: javascript

I'm planning to make a JavaScript app that can merge multiple files, currently it can merge text files.

```
 <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<script>
var output = [];

function mergeFiles(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;

  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      output.push(e.target.result);
      document.getElementById("output").value = output.join("\n");
    });
    reader.readAsText(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", mergeFiles);

</script>
```

I've plan to make use of some regular expression to merge html files too.
Is it a good approach, I mean the way I'm doing it...

Comment: Why are you using `(function(theFile) { ... })(f);` if you are not even using `f` inside the closure?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you want someone to comment on your code, try [codereview.se].

Comment: I would have used jquery instead of raw DOM code. More importantly, although I don't know FileReader, I'd guess that there's no guarantee of the order in which `load` events are fired, i.e. you'll probably end up with an array of files in the wrong order. Do you care about this?